# After Insert Trigger not Working

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insertafter

I'm trying to run an after insert trigger but it does not work, is there any way to see a log of it?

Here is my code

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SUBSID_INSERT] on [dbo].[STUDENT_MASTER] AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @numrows int, @hostname char(30), @sysuser char(30);

SELECT @numrows = @@rowcount;
IF @numrows = 0 RETURN;

SELECT @hostname = substring(hostname, 1, 30)
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = @@spid;

SELECT @sysuser = substring(system_user, 1, 30);

INSERT INTO insert statement,  


FROM STUDENT_MASTER JOIN INSERTED I ON STUDENT_MASTER.ID_NUM = I.ID_NUM
JOIN NAME_MASTER ON NAME_MASTER.ID_NUM = STUDENT_MASTER.ID_NUM


WHERE 
STUDENT_MASTER.id_num not in ( select DISTINCT id_num from subsid_master where subsid_cde LIKE '0%')

END

GO
```

Comment: *Does not work* - how!?!?! Does it (a) not do anything? (b) throw an error? (c) do something wrong?

Comment: Nothing, it's like the parameters are returning 0 rows but if I run the script it does do the insert.

Comment: What is "INSERT INTO insert statement, "? Does the trigger complile with this in there...

Answer (score 4):

You are checking `@@ROWCOUNT` after declaring a variable. This will always show the result of the last statement (in this case `0`), so stop doing that. Instead just use:

```
SELECT @numrows = COUNT(*) FROM inserted;
```

I see lots of other potential improvements but this is precisely why it currently appears to be "not working."

Comment: +1: @AaronBertrand, your answer is obviously correct, but I was wondering if this check is even necessary? Will a `AFTER INSERT` trigger fire if the `inserted` table is empty?